# 3D Scrolling Scene - OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d, scroll, scene

I'm trying to draw clouds in the window and animate them towards the camera.  The problem I'm having is that I want to do this continuously without anything being abruptly redrawn.  Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Here is the code:

```
#include <gl/glut.h>

int width = 800, height = 600;
float theta = 0, distance1 = -600, distance2 = -600;
void drawCloud()
{
glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(1,0,-2);
glutSolidSphere(4,10,10);
glTranslated(-2,0,-5);
glutSolidSphere(4,10,10);
glTranslated(-1,0,3);
glutSolidSphere(4,10,10);
glPopMatrix();

}

void drawCloudFormation()
{
glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(-60,30,-300);
drawCloud();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(15,3,-150);
drawCloud();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(50,30,-200);
drawCloud();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(-15,-15,-250);
drawCloud();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(25,-25,-100);
drawCloud();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(-30,0,-50);
drawCloud();
glPopMatrix();
}

void display()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
//glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(0,0,distance1);
drawCloudFormation();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(0,0,distance1-200);
glScaled(-1,1,1);
drawCloudFormation();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(0,0,distance2-400);
glScaled(1,1,-1);
drawCloudFormation();
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(0,0,distance2-600);
glScaled(-1,1,1);
glScaled(1,1,-1);
drawCloudFormation();
glPopMatrix();

glutSwapBuffers();
}

void idle()
{
theta += 0.2;
if (theta == 360) theta = 360;

distance1 += 1;
if (distance1 > 200) distance1 = -600;

distance2 += 1;
if (distance2 > 600) distance2 = -600;

glutPostRedisplay();
}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 200);
glutCreateWindow("Space Ship");
glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);


glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(120, 1, 0.1, 600);
//glOrtho(-2, 2, -2, 2, 0.1, 200);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
//gluLookAt(0, 0, -200, 0, 0, -600, 0, 1, 0);

glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutIdleFunc(idle);

glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: What is happening/what errors are you getting, how is it different from what you want to happen, what have you tried to fix it? There's no way for us to just fix your code without knowing the problem, *especially* in graphics.

Comment: Well what I want to happen is for one set of clouds to be drawn behind one another continuously.  Initially, I had one distance variable for all 4 cloud formations. That won't work because the first formation will not be redrawn in the background until the fourth formation clears a certain distance.  So now I have 2 distance variables in hopes that once the first group of cloud formations covers a certain distance is will be redrawn in the background while the second cloud formation is still moving towards the camera.

Comment: Right now what happens is that some cloud formations will be abruptly redrawn in the middle of their animations (pop in, pop out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [particle systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_system).

You essentially want a rectangular emitter on the far side of your scene spewing clouds (particles) with a fixed velocity toward the camera.  When the clouds move behind the camera mark them as inactive and the particle system will spawn a new ones back at the emitter.

Comment: Thanks very much.. It helps to know what you are looking for.